# Differentiability of $\cos{|x|}$ and $\sin{|x|}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Define differentiability of  $\cos{|x|}$ and $\sin{|x|}$ at $x=0$

It is said that $\cos|x|$ is continuous and $\sin|x|$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.
$$
Lf'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{\cos|0+h|-\cos|0|}{h}=\lim_{h\to{0}}\frac{\cos h-1}{h}=Rf'(0)
$$
Thus $\cos|x|$ is continuous. Fine, but applying chain rule, let $|x|=t$
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\cos|x|\bigg|_{x=0}=\frac{d}{dx}\cos t\bigg|_{x=0}=\frac{d(\cos t)}{dt}.\frac{dt}{dx}\bigg|_{x=0}=-\sin t.\frac{dt}{dx}\bigg|_{x=0}=-\sin t.\frac{d|x|}{dx}\bigg|_{x=0}
$$
As $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x$=$0$, how can we define the derivative of $\cos|x|$ at $x=0$ ?

Comment: $\cos|x| = \cos x$ in a neighborhood of $x=0$ ...

Comment: @MartinR In _any_ neighbourhood of $x = 0$, in fact.

Comment: @Arthur: You are right of course. (Apparently I thought of $|\cos x|$ ...)

Comment: Both $\sin|x|$ and $\cos|x|$ are continuous at $x=0$. I think you mean that the derivative of $\sin|x|$ doesn't exist at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the functions, $|x|,\;\cos(x),\;\sin(x)$ are continuous, and since a composition of continuous functions is continuous, it follows that the functions $\cos(|x|)$, and $\sin(|x|)$ are both continuous.

With regard to differentiability . . .

By the chain rule, if two functions are both differentiable, their composition is also differentiable.

However, if one or both of two functions is not differentiable, the chain rule is not applicable, so yields no information.

Thus, for the question of whether $\cos(|x|)$ or $\sin(|x|)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, the chain rule doesn't apply.

Instead, we can argue as follows . . .

If $x\ge 0$, then $\cos(|x|)=\cos(x)$.

If $x < 0$, then $\cos(|x|)=\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$.

Thus, $\cos(|x|)=\cos(x)$, for all $x$.

Hence, since $\cos(x)$ is differentiable, so is $\cos(|x|)$.

On the other hand, $\sin(|x|)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, since at $x=0$, the slope from the right is $1$, and the slope from the left is $-1$.

More precisely, let $f(x) = \sin(|x|)$.

If we restrict the domain of $f$ to $[0,\infty)$, we have $f(x) = \sin(|x|)=\sin(x)$, so on that domain, we have $f'(0)=\cos(0)=1$.

If we restrict the domain of $f$ to $(-\infty,0]$, we have $f(x) = \sin(|x|)=\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$, so on that domain, we have $f'(0)=-\cos(0)=-1$.

Comment: Thanx. i can see that, but i think my doubt arises when applying the chain rule as a stated.

Comment: The chain rule applies to _differentiable_ functions, so it doesn't apply when one of the components of the chain is not differentiable (and in that case, it gives no information).

Comment: so u mean chain rule chain not be applied to find the derivative of $\cos|x|$ at $x=0$ even though it is differentiable there ?

Comment: Right.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Just through definition. For small $|h|>0$, then 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\cos|h|-1}{h}=\dfrac{\cos h-1}{h},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\cos|h|-1}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\cos h-1}{h}=-\sin 0=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: this is fine, this how we check differentiability right. But, when applying chain rule i see $\frac{d|x|}{dx}\bigg|_{x=0}$, which i thought is not defined. Why do i have a confusion there ?

Comment: You need some regulation before applying Chain Rule, both of them must exist first before applying Chain Rule, Chain Rule is not to use to prove existence.

Comment: @ ss1729 we also have $x^2=|x|^2$ and you cannot apply a chain rule (at point 0) to RHS but it  doesn't mean the non-differentiability of the function $x^2.$

Answer (score 0):

(1) Both $\cos|x|$ and $\sin|x|$ are continuous at $x=0$.

(2) $\cos|x|$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\cos|x|-\cos|0|}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\cos x -\cos 0}{x-0}=\left.\frac{d\cos x}{dx}\right|_{x=0}=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\cos|x|-\cos|0|}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\cos (-x) -\cos 0}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\cos x -\cos 0}{x-0}=\left.\frac{d\cos x}{dx}\right|_{x=0}=0$$

Therefore $\displaystyle \left.\frac{d\cos |x|}{dx}\right|_{x=0}$ exists and equals to $\displaystyle \left.\frac{d\cos x}{dx}\right|_{x=0}$.

(3) $\sin|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin|x|-\sin|0|}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin x -\sin 0}{x-0}=\left.\frac{d\sin x}{dx}\right|_{x=0}=1$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sin|x|-\sin|0|}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin (-x) -\sin 0}{x-0}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{-(\sin x -\sin 0)}{x-0}=\left.\frac{d(-\sin x)}{dx}\right|_{x=0}=-1$$

Therefore $\displaystyle \left.\frac{d\sin |x|}{dx}\right|_{x=0}$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

1) Here is a graph of $f=\sin \vert x \vert$ where $x$ ranges over $-1$ to $1$:

[image]

There is a "corner" at $x=0$, so $f$ is not differentiable there.

2) $g=\cos \vert x \vert$ where $-2 \leq x \leq 2$

[image]

> How can we define the derivative of $\cos \vert x \vert $ at $x=0$ ?

If $h \neq 0$, then the two distinct points $(0,g(0))$ and $(0+h,g(0+h))$ determine a straight line whose slope is $$\frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h}$$ The tangent line at $(0,g(0))$ seems to be the limit in some sense of these secant lines as $h$ approaches $0$. The slope of the tangent line through $(0,g(0))$ should be $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h}$$  With this limit exist then $g$ is differentiable at $0$. Refer This computation given by CY Aries